# OOP in Java: problem with constructor and methods

Tags: java, oop, methods, constructor

I am new to Java and I am trying to write a class with constructors and methods that adds and divides two numbers, and also compares if one object is larger or equal than the other. But I am getting an error: `The method plus(int) in the type Compare is not applicable for the arguments (Compare)`. what's wrong?

Here's the code:

```
public class Compare {
    // fields
    private int number;
    private int plus;
    private double div; 

    // constructor
    public Compare (int n) {
        number = n;
    }


    public int plus (int x) {
        return this.number + x;
    }

    public int div (int x) {
        return this.number / x;
    }   

    public boolean isLargerThan (int x) {
        return this.number > x;
    }       

    public boolean isEqualTo (int x) {
        return this.number == x;
    }           

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Compare n1 = new Compare(9);
        Compare n2 = new Compare(4);

        Compare sum = n1.plus(n2);

        Compare div = n1.div(n2);

        boolean check1 = sum.isLargerThan(n1);

        boolean check2 = div.isLargerThan(n2);

        boolean check3 = div.isEqualto(sum);            

    }       

}
```

The requirement is to create sum and div objects using Compare constructor that will be equal to n1 plus n2, with plus method or division as applicable.

Comment: `boolean check1 = sum.isLargerThan(n1);`, what's the type of n1 and what you expected by defining `public boolean isLargerThan (int x) {`?

Comment: n1 must be initialized by the Compare. So that methods can be applied to it. The method public boolean isLargerThan is to be applied to n1, to compare with n2 or any object initialized by the Compare.

Comment: What SMA is saying is that you declare the methods to take `integers`, yet you pass it a `Compare`. What do you expect the compiler to do when you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that here you want a new Compare, containing the sum.

```
public Compare plus (int x) {
    return new Compare(number + x);
}

public Compare plus (Compare x) {
    return new Compare(number + x.number);
}
```

This also is implied by expecting a Compare object, not an int as shown.

With that `Compare` would become immutable, which is very good, as you then can share objects in different variables without problems (changing one variable's value changing other variables' values).

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(number);
}

public int intValue() {
    return number;
}
```

Comment: I have added a `toString` method that always is used when doing `System.out.println(n1);` Otherwise the parent class `Object.toString()` is used that just prints class name + '@' plus "address" of the object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is for the "plus", "div", "isLargerThan" and "isEqualTo" methods in "Compare" class the argument/return type is of type "int". But in "main" function you are passing the object and expecting object of type "Compare".

To fix it either change the argument/return type to "Compare" for those methods in "Compare" class or pass the "int" value as parameter and get "int" value in "main" function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here :

> Compare sum = n1.plus(n2);
>
> Compare div = n1.div(n2);

methods : `plus` and `div` return `int` value not an objet of Class `Compare`.

public int plus (int x) {
    return this.number + x;
}

public int div (int x) {
    return this.number / x;
}

---

```
Add getter method in Compare Class.

public int getNumber(){
return number;
}
```

---

Use below code and try to run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Compare sum = new Compare(9);
    Compare divObj = new Compare(4);

    sum.plus(n2);

    divObj.div(n2);

    boolean check1 = sum.isLargerThan(sum.getNumber());

    boolean check2 = divObj.isLargerThan(divObj.getNumber());

    boolean check3 = divObj.isEqualto(sum.getNiumber());            

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `plus` and `div` methods take an `int` and return an `int` and you are trying to receive their output in a `Compare` object. Also, `isLargerThan` takes an `int` and not a `Compare`.